# maphilight plugin start/active poly

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a map loaded in a photo. I would like to create an area on the map that is is no longer active.  It should be inactive at all times, not just when clicked on or hovered over. How could I make this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the property `neverOn` to true for that specific area:

```
$('specific_area').data('maphilight', {neverOn:false}).trigger('neverOn.maphilight');
```

You can take a look to the rest of the properties you can set at the [plugin docs site](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/).